# How to use Kafka consumer "seek" properly to go back to uncommitted offsets for all partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka

With the Java Kafka Consumer `seek()` function it requires we pass in the `TopicPartion` and `Offest`. However, I thought this seek method would take a collection of subscribed TopicPartitions for my consumer.

Here is my example I am trying to handle.

Consumer A is subscribed to topic "test-topic" partitions 1 and 2. I read messages from each partition when I call `poll()`. I process some messages but my application gets an exception. I do not call `commitSync()`. Now I want to rewind to those offsets that I retrieved on my last `poll()` and try to reprocess them. So how should I do this? Do I need to go through the last committed offsets for each topic partition and call `seek()` for each partition? Will calling `seek()` multiple times only accept the last `seek()` that is called? As I said I want to make sure my consumer goes back for all partitions so I do not lose any data on any assigned partitions.

Answer (score 1):

> I process some messages but my application gets an exception. I do not
>   call commitSync()

If you do not call `commitSync()` the messages will not be committed. If suppose the exception kills your program, then after restart the consumer typically reads it from the last committed offset.

You may also want to check [auto.offset.reset](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#auto.offset.reset) and set it to `earliest`.

Check if your messages are auto committed, since you are doing `commitSync()` you don't need auto commit i.e. `enable.auto.commit` can be set to `false` (by default it is `true` in Confluent Kafka)

In case, your program is not terminated by the exception, you always have the consumed records. You can retry processing each record and then commit.

```
ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
for(ConsumerRecord record: records)
{
   tryProcess(record, 3);
}
consumer.commitSync();

void tryProcess(ConsumerRecord record, int maxRetries) {
    if(maxRetries < 1) {
        log.warn("max retries exhausted for record");
        return;
    }
    try {
         process(record);
    } catch(Exception ex){ 
        tryProcess(record, --maxRetries);
    }
}
```

You can also try processing batch of records with retries instead of each record like `tryProcess(records, 3)` where records correspond to `ConsumerRecords` and the batch is retried 3 times. I don't think there is a need for seeking.

---

> I'm still curious about the usage of the seek() api though

`seek()` may be used for example, when we are not using subscriptions i.e. `consumer.subscribe()` but rather `consumer.assign()` which we usually do when we just want to peek (view) the messages in the topic, for example like console consumer. Sometimes, we may need to see some messages after a certain offset, or the last *n* messages etc without actually doing anything with them, but just displaying.

Comment: my application is not crashing - and I need to keep the consumer alive so I'm not restarting the application it must be self-healing.

Comment: In that case, do you see any problem with the above code snippet? Is the solution feasible for you?

Comment: Yes, I guess this would work if I needed it to just keep retrying until it succeeded. I'm still curious about the usage of the `seek()` api though.

Comment: @alex I updated the answer with a possibie use case for `seek()`